How do I find out total size of all photos between 2 random dates in Google Photos?
Between two dates of my choosing, I need to find out the total size occupied by all media (photos, videos, screenshots, etc.) in Google Photos.
For example, I want to find out what is the total size of all media (photos, videos, screenshots, etc.) between 4 Jul 2024 and 2 Aug 2024.
